# Generics with json Subtype in java

Tags: java, json, generics

I have a service wherein I use entities with following structure

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String productId;
    private List<MobileCompany<?>> companies;

    // ...
}


public class MobileCompany<T> extends Company<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4809948191835736752
    private String  simType;

    // ....
}        

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name= "samsung", value = Samsung.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name= "htc",value = Htc.class)})
public class Company<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8869676577723436716L;
    private T info;
    private String type;

    // ...
}
```

My service looks similar to below

```
 Product sample(@RequestBody Product product) {
     ....// not doing any update on product
     return product;
 }
```

with request as below ..

```
{  
   id:0903673902783,
   companies:[  
      {  
         simType:"DUAL",
         type:"samsung"
      }
   ]
}
```

and get back below response

```
{  
   id:0903673902783,
   companies:[  
      {  
         simType:"DUAL",
         type:"MobileCompany"
      }
   ]
}
```

Why am I getting type as "MobileCompany" instead of "samsung" ?

***Note*** : "MobileCompany" is the name of the class which extends Company and in the   response I am getting "MobileCompany" as type instead of the type specified in  the request. Product is having list of MobileCompany.

Comment: There are some relevant parts of the code missing in this post.

Comment: Could you point out any examples of missing code? as this is all I got , in case of entity structure I have removed only getters and setters .

Comment: Well, for example the string `"MobileCompany"` is nowhere found. Some part of the code must put it there.

Comment: "MobileCompany"  is actually the name of the class which extends Company<T> and  in the response  I am getting "MobileCompany" as type instead of the type specified  in the request. Product is having list of MobileCompany<T>    I have updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: Don't put more information into comments. Update your question instead. And read [mcve].

Comment: @GhostCat Done.Thanks.